# Auto-size text to fit image container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my text responsive over my image so that they scale together, but can't make the text scale with the image and still keep its position. I'm using `vw` to scale the text, but have no idea to make it keep its position on the image? I want my text to shrink parallel to my image and the ratio between them to stay the same if they shrink (responsive).

I've tried changing the image and container to absolute, yet the problem remains.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-height: 900px;
  max-width: 1364px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: bisque;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 0.6vw;
}

.top-left-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 620px;
  text-align: left;
}

.top-middle-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 1140px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img alt="lagaremeny" height="703" src="lagaremeny.png" width="1376">
  <div class="top-left-text">

    <div class="auto-style1">

      <strong>Sallader</strong>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Kycklingsallad 69kr</li>
      <li>Amerikansk sallad 69kr</li>
      <li>Grekisk sallad 69kr</li>
      <li>Tonfisk, ägg och rödlök 69kr</li>
      <li>Västkuströra och ägg 74kr</li>
      <li>Skagenröra och ägg 74kr</li>
      <li>Salami och sallads ost 74kr</li>
      <li>Kebabröra 69kr</li>
      <li>Räkor Handskalade Lyxräkor (MFC märkt) 94kr</li>
    </ul>
    Alla våra sallader består av en bas med isbergssallad,<br> ruccola, röd mangold, röda blad, máche, gurka,<br> mix av körsbergstomater och pasta/eller mer<br> grönsallad och paprika.<br> I alla sallader ingår dressing och bröd.
    <br><br>Dressing: Vitlök, Mango curry, Vinaigrette, Curry,<br> Rhodeisland, Blue cheese, Honung o dijong, Mangoraja.
  </div>
  <div class="top-middle-text">
    <div class="auto-style1">
      <strong>Arbetarmackor</strong></div>
    <ul>
      <li>Ägg och biff</li>
      <li>Ägg och bacon</li>
      <li>Ägg och korv</li>
      <li>Ägg, köttbullar och rödbetssallad</li>
      <li>Ägg och sill</li>
      <li>Ägg och västkustsallad</li>
      <li>Leverpastej</li>
      <li>Ost och paprika</li>
      <li>Ost och skinka</li>
      <li>Köttbullar och rödbetssallad</li>
      <li>Rostbiff och potatissallad</li>
    </ul>
    Alla arbetarmackor: 59kr/st.
    <br>Standardtillbehör: sallad, gurka och tomat.
  </div>
```

When i try to scale down the window the text shrinks but keeps it position as the image decreases and changes position

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want to accomplish. Do you want your font size to be responsive and keep text in the same place no matter what screen size?

Comment: I want my text to shrink parallell to my image and the ratio between them to stay the same if they shrink (responsive).

Comment: Please provide the html code so we can help you further.

Comment: html has been provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this jQuery plugin [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/) if you're okay with using external libraries.

Otherwise, here's a solution that uses the window `resize` event listener and updates the font-size (calculated from the parent container's width).

You can include the JavaScript in your html file by moving it inside of a script tag like so:

```
<script defer>
  setFontSize('container', 14)

  function setFontSize (containerClassName, fontScale) {
    resizeFontInContainer() // initialize the page with scaled font
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFontInContainer) // add event listener for window resize

    function resizeFontInContainer () {
      let containers = document.getElementsByClassName(containerClassName)
      for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
        let containerWidth = containers[i].offsetWidth
        containers[i].style.fontSize = `${containerWidth * fontScale / 1000}px`
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

FYI, I had to change some of your CSS to make this work for your specific case.

```js
setFontSize('container', 14)

function setFontSize (containerClassName, fontScale) {
  resizeFontInContainer() // initialize the page with scaled font
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFontInContainer) // add event listener for window resize

  function resizeFontInContainer () {
    let containers = document.getElementsByClassName(containerClassName)
    for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
      let containerWidth = containers[i].offsetWidth
      containers[i].style.fontSize = `${containerWidth * fontScale / 1000}px`
    }
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-height: 900px;
  max-width: 1364px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: bisque;
}

.top-left-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-middle-text {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  top: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <img alt="lagaremeny" height="703" src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="1376">
    <div class="top-middle-text">
      <div class="auto-style1">
        <strong>Arbetarmackor</strong></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Ägg och biff</li>
        <li>Ägg och bacon</li>
        <li>Ägg och korv</li>
        <li>Ägg, köttbullar och rödbetssallad</li>
        <li>Ägg och sill</li>
        <li>Ägg och västkustsallad</li>
        <li>Leverpastej</li>
        <li>Ost och paprika</li>
        <li>Ost och skinka</li>
        <li>Köttbullar och rödbetssallad</li>
        <li>Rostbiff och potatissallad</li>
      </ul>
      Alla arbetarmackor: 59kr/st.
      <br>Standardtillbehör: sallad, gurka och tomat.
    </div>
    <div class="top-left-text">

      <div class="auto-style1">

        <strong>Sallader</strong>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>Kycklingsallad 69kr</li>
        <li>Amerikansk sallad 69kr</li>
        <li>Grekisk sallad 69kr</li>
        <li>Tonfisk, ägg och rödlök 69kr</li>
        <li>Västkuströra och ägg 74kr</li>
        <li>Skagenröra och ägg 74kr</li>
        <li>Salami och sallads ost 74kr</li>
        <li>Kebabröra 69kr</li>
        <li>Räkor Handskalade Lyxräkor (MFC märkt) 94kr</li>
      </ul>
      Alla våra sallader består av en bas med isbergssallad,<br> ruccola, röd mangold, röda blad, máche, gurka,<br> mix
      av körsbergstomater och pasta/eller mer<br> grönsallad och paprika.<br> I alla sallader ingår dressing och bröd.
      <br><br>Dressing: Vitlök, Mango curry, Vinaigrette, Curry,<br> Rhodeisland, Blue cheese, Honung o dijong,
      Mangoraja.
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if this is what you were attempting to do. If not, please let me know more specifically what you were looking for.